# File Upload Feature Specifics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, backbone.js

So I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I'm building a website and I'd like to implement a upload for users to upload images as an avatar or a screenshot in their comment. I'm still quite a beginner (coding for 7 weeks) and I'm writing this website using BackboneJS and Ruby on Rails. I think I need just a form and an input tag within the HTML template that allows users to select a picture from their local system to my application. My question is, once I parse the data (assuming I parse it because Ive been parsing all data into JSON).

Where does it go?

I have read that its bad to store the image into my postgreSQL database.

But where else would it go in the back-end?

Is my application just going to download what they upload and keep it in a folder that is assigned to each specific user?

If anybody could explain it at a pretty basic level, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning how to do file upload on rails this was really helpful for me 
[carrierwave-file-uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

You will need to add this 2 gems to your gem file

```
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
```

Create a uploader
**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end
end
```

last but not least you need your form

```
<%= form_for @painting, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

I hope that this helps. 
Keep on coding. You are doing great for 7 weeks